# How to change categorical data in any column in pandas dataframe with respect to numeric data in other column (mapping)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, exploratory-data-analysis

i want to map the the AQI column with AQI_Bucket column in pandas dataframe
i tried it using for loop but couldnt get it

```
for aqi in df['AQI']:
    col1,col2 = df['AQI'],df['AQI_Bucket']
    _col1,_col2 = col1[0],col2[0]
    if df[aqi] == df['AQI_Bucket']:
        
        if pd.isnull(_col2):
            if _col1 in range(51):
                _col2 = "Good"
            elif _col1 in range(51, 101):
                _col2 = "Satisfactory"
            elif _col1 in range(101,201):
                _col2 = "Moderate"
            elif _col1 in range(201, 301):
                _col2 = "Poor"
            elif _col1 in range(301, 401):
                _col2 == "Very Poor"
            elif _col1 in range(401, 500):
                _col2 == "Severe"
```

Comment: Hello, please read about [how to make good, reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: From what I infer from your code, you want to fill null values of `AQI_Bucket` column based on the value of `AQI`  (`range(51) => "Good"`, etc). Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I know what you're trying to do here, and you should definitely use the `.cut()` method:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#generate a DF with 2 columns, 1 with random values, the other with fixed values
df = pd.DataFrame({'AQI_rand': np.random.randint(500, size=6),\
                   'AQI_fixed': [25,75,150,250,350,450]}) #I've made this one to check if the "bins" were correct

#create the first "AQI_Bucket" column linked to "AQI_rand"
df['AQI_Bucket'] = pd.cut(df['AQI_rand'], bins=[0,50,100,200,300,400,500], labels=['Good','Satisfactory','Moderate','Poor','Very Poor','Severe'])

#create the first "AQI_Bucket2" column linked to "AQI_fixed"
df['AQI_Bucket2'] = pd.cut(df['AQI_fixed'], bins=[0,50,100,200,300,400,500], labels=['Good','Satisfactory','Moderate','Poor','Very Poor','Severe'])

#rearrange columns order
df = df.iloc[:,[0,2,1,3]]
df
```

| index | AQI_rand | AQI_Bucket | AQI_fixed | AQI_Bucket2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 326 | Very Poor | 25 | Good |
| 1 | 238 | Poor | 75 | Satisfactory |
| 2 | 182 | Moderate | 150 | Moderate |
| 3 | 341 | Very Poor | 250 | Poor |
| 4 | 88 | Satisfactory | 350 | Very Poor |
| 5 | 459 | Severe | 450 | Severe |

*If it's not what you were looking for, please let me know and I'll delete my answer, otherwise check mark it* ✅